# d3 Animation with transform translate on force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout, translate-animation

i have problem with my animation. I call the tick function to animate my nodes and want now to animate the node after a click on it to an specific position. Thats working also but without animation the node just jump to the position without animation.

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes([]) // coming from a JSON file
    .linkDistance([]) // coming from a JSON file
    .charge(-750)
    .gravity(0)
    .on("tick", tick);
```

....

```
function tick() {

  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {     
            return "translate(" + (d.x) + "," + (d.y) + ")";          
      });
}
```

Animation Call:

```
d3.select(tmp_this.parentNode)
  .transition()
  .attr('transform', function(e){
      var position = "translate(" + (500) + "," + (500) + ")";
     return position;
  });
```

Comment: You need something like `.duration(1000)` after `.transition()`.

Comment: That's not the problem, i have no animation also with duration. I animate befor the radius of the nodes with:
    d3.select(tmp_this)
      .transition().attr("r", '70px');

And that's animate the radius without problem.

Comment: Same issue for me, and I still can't figure out what's going on